# how to port c code into java? starting instructions

Tags: java, c++, c, porting

I am working on porting a library over from C++ to Java. I want to know the first / initial steps to  begin this port. I am not sure how will I test / debug? I could just start with the "main" file and begin rewriting code, but how and when do I test what I am doing? When I am done the COMPLETE port? How do I start about this, any help would be great.

Any cross platform / etc compiler would help? let me know the steps please

Comment: I would recommend that you approach this as a new library project in Java, and follow the usual pattern: analyze, design, implement, test. Use the original code as a guide for the implementation, and if the original lib is tested, borrow all those tests and implement them in Java.

Comment: What tests do you have in place for C++ now? Make sure they run stably before you start, and make sure they stay stable at every step you take. If you don't have C++ tests, write them first and port along with the code.

Comment: Please be consistent. Are you talking about C or C++ code? They are not the same thing!

Comment: It is all C code. I do not have unit tests / etc since this is an open source library. Just have source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the old library in JNI and call it from your unit test to ensure the ported code does exactly the same thing as the old code.

Comment: It's all C. I do not have unit tests or anything for this, it is an open source library. Only the c files.

Comment: +1 Easiest method is to wrap not port.

Comment: JNA may be easier than JNI. It's slightly slower, but not perceptibly so per call.

Answer (score 1):

You can port piece-by-piece, bottom-up, and test each piece individually with [junit](http://www.junit.org/) or [testng](http://testng.org/).

Comment: Guys I did not write the C/C++ code, it is a library I need for doing something. It is a lot of files so I need a systematic way of doing this. I do not know of the tests implemented for c/c++, they are not made public.

Comment: @user809240 - Part of porting something non-trivial is understanding what the pieces do, and confirming that you've successfully implemented your understanding. Unit tests provide you a means to do so. While it would be nice to have unit tests for the legacy code, it's not common, and it's not necessary. You can write new tests. You can avoid writing tests by using JNI as Peter Lawrey mentions above.