# A tool like Jazillian to convert C to Java?

Tags: java, c, programming-languages, port

I see and hear a lot about Jazillian when I look for information on coverting C to Java. But I cannot find any information on what happened to this wonderful tool and where to download it?

Does anyone have any insight into it? I want to download Jazillian or any other good alternative?

Comment: Converting C to Java should be *impossible* for quite a bit of C code (namely, most of the code that has any reason to be written in C in the first place) and the results will be ugly and non-idiomatic at best for everything else. Where did you hear about this?

Comment: Please read your own question next time before posting it. You managed to write Jazillian in a number of different (and incorrect) ways. Something that should be easy to catch.

Comment: I would gather from the complete lack of any clues to obtain this software using Google, that it didn't survive the market for a reason.

Comment: What makes you think this was a `wonderful` tool?

Comment: You mention in [a previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748778/how-to-port-c-code-into-java-starting-instructions) that you're converting an open source library? Does this post still refer to the same library? If so, tell us what it is and perhaps there is a Java equivalent we can suggest.

Comment: Am I seriously missing the point or does this project already come with wrappers for various languages including Java? I don't know the project at all, but from the link you just posted that seems to be the case.....

Comment: You are not missing the point, you are right, but I need to use it on a Blackberry device hence wrappers do not do the job. The code NEEDS to be ported (owner of code agrees)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use JNI.  That way you don't have to convert anything, but rather send requests to your native code and have it return the results as data structures that you can manipulate in your Java program.  this code is obviously not cross platform, but depending on the scope of your project this could be the fastest way to extend a C app with new Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly [Cibyl](http://code.google.com/p/cibyl/) can compile C libraries into executable Java bytecode. I don't know of a specific tool to convert the C code to actual Java code, except for porting it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of tools out there. They're called programmers. You should get one of those to do it.

There isn't a one-to-one mapping between C and Java. C can do lots of stuff Java can't do (pointers spring to mind as the obvious one), and the same is true of Java. C doesn't even have classes. Any machine translation would result in terrifying code. You're far better off doing it by hand. If the project you want to translate has unit tests, you should *definitely* do those by hand before you translate the code under test. If not, perhaps you should write some unit tests for the code you're translating first, because otherwise you're going to screw it up.

This all assumes you have a good reason for translating code from one language to another in the first place. Keep good hold of it. Those are rare.

Comment: oooh, am I going to -1 this for calling programmers "tools"? :p

Comment: @Bart: Damn Americanisms. I've never heard anyone use "tool" in that context this side of the pond. I meant no offence to programmers in general, honest. :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't down vote. Saw the humor of the remark.

Comment: Good to know. I've elaborated more on my answer.